# Erro de insert de data php

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou tentando inserir data em um registro php, só que ele está apresentando um erro, que eu imagino que seja bem simples, mas anda me tomando um tempinho precioso.

Já tentei colocar `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->data_fundacao))` aonde eu envio o parâmetro.
Nas duas tentativas, em uma, ele cadastra `1969-12-31 21:00:00` e em outra ele cadastra `2069-12-31 00:00:00`

Nos meus testes eu vi que ele pega a data certinho, só que não insere.

```
<div class="input-group has-feedback" id="divDataFundacao">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control input-group" name="txtDataFundacao" placeholder="Ex.: 03/03/1995" id="txtDataFundacao" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return BloqueiaLetras(event)"                                               onkeyup="mascara(this, mdata);">
</div>
```

`PHP`

```
//pega os dados no form
$dataFundacao = $_POST['txtDataFundacao'];

//envia a classe de insert
$Partner->setDataFundacao($dataFundacao);

//na classe
    private $data_fundacao;


 public function setDataFundacao($data_fundacao){
        return $this->data_fundacao = $data_fundacao;
    }

   $stmt->bindParam(":data_fundacao",date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->data_fundacao)),PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Qual o formato vindo em `$this->data_fundacao`?

Comment: Data formato brasileiro. Quando mando pro banco, mando com o formato do mysql

Comment: Valeu pela a ideia @MarcelodeAndrade, fazer a conversão antes de enviar funcionou